# Do agda programs necessarily terminate?

Tags: emacs, agda, halting-problem

It has been stated a few places that all agda programs terminate.  However I can construct a function like this:

```
stall : ∀ n → ℕ
stall 0 = 0
stall x = stall x
```

The syntax highlighter doesn't seem to like it, but there are no compilation errors.

Computing the normal form of `stall 0` results in `0`.  Computing the result of `stall 1` causes Emacs to hang in what looks a lot like a non-terminating loop.

Is this a bug?  Or can Agda sometimes run forever?  Or is something more subtle going on?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In fact, there are compilation errors. The `agda` executable finds an error and passes that information to `agda-mode` in Emacs, which in turn does the syntax highlighting to let you know there was an error. We can take a look at what happens if we use `agda` directly. Here's the file I'm using:

```
module C1 where

open import Data.Nat

loop : ℕ → ℕ
loop 0 = 0
loop x = loop x
```

Now, we call `agda -i../lib-0.7/src -i. C1.agda` (don't mind the `-i` parameters, they just let the executable know where to look for the standard library) and we get the error:

```
Termination checking failed for the following functions:
  loop
Problematic calls:
  loop x
    (at D:\Agda\tc\C1.agda:7,10-14)
```

This is indeed compilation error. Such errors prevent us from `import`ing this module from other modules or compiling it. For example, if we add these lines to the file above:

```
open import IO

main = run (putStrLn "")
```

And compile the module using `C-c C-x C-c`, `agda-mode` complains:

```
You can only compile modules without unsolved metavariables
or termination checking problems.
```

---

Other kinds of compilation errors include type checking problems:

```
module C2 where

open import Data.Bool
open import Data.Nat

type-error : ℕ → Bool
type-error n = n
__________________________

D:\Agda\tc\C2.agda:7,16-17
ℕ !=< Bool of type Set

when checking that the expression n has type Bool
```

Failed positivity check:

```
module C3 where

data Positivity : Set where
  bad : (Positivity → Positivity) → Positivity
__________________________

D:\Agda\tc\C3.agda:3,6-16
Positivity is not strictly positive, because it occurs to the left
of an arrow in the type of the constructor bad in the definition of
Positivity.
```

Or unsolved metavariables:

```
module C4 where

open import Data.Nat

meta : ∀ {a} → ℕ
meta = 0
__________________________

Unsolved metas at the following locations:
  D:\Agda\tc\C4.agda:5,11-12
```

---

Now, you rightly noticed that some errors are "dead ends", while others let you carry on writing your program. That's because some errors are worse than others. For example, if you get unsolved metavariable, chances are that you'll be able to just fill in the missing information and everything will be okay.

As for hanging the compiler: checking or compiling a module shouldn't cause `agda` to loop. Let's try to force the type checker to loop. We'll add more stuff into the module `C1`:

```
data _≡_ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : A → Set a where
  refl : x ≡ x

test : loop 1 ≡ 1
test = refl
```

Now, to check that `refl` is correct expression of that type, `agda` has to evaluate `loop 1`. However, since the termination check failed, `agda` will not unroll `loop` (and end up in an infinite loop).

However, `C-c C-n` really forces `agda` to try to evaluate the expression (you basically tell it "I know what I'm doing"), so naturally you get into an infinite loop.

---

Incidentally, you can make `agda` loop if you disable the termination check:

```
{-# NO_TERMINATION_CHECK #-}
loop : ℕ → ℕ
loop 0 = 0
loop x = loop x

data _≡_ {a} {A : Set a} (x : A) : A → Set a where
  refl : x ≡ x

test : loop 1 ≡ 1
test = refl
```

Which ends up in:

```
stack overflow
```

---

As a rule of thumb: if you can make `agda` loop by checking (or compiling) a module without using any compiler pragmas, then this is indeed a bug and should be reported on the [bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/agda/issues). That being said, there are few ways to make non-terminating program if you are willing to use compiler pragmas. We've already seen `{-# NO_TERMINATION_CHECK #-}`, here are some other ways:

```
{-# OPTIONS --no-positivity-check #-}
module Boom where

data Bad (A : Set) : Set where
  bad : (Bad A → A) → Bad A

unBad : {A : Set} → Bad A → Bad A → A
unBad (bad f) = f

fix : {A : Set} → (A → A) → A
fix f = (λ x → f (unBad x x)) (bad λ x → f (unBad x x))

loop : {A : Set} → A
loop = fix λ x → x
```

This one relies on a data type which is not strictly positive. Or we could force `agda` to accept `Set : Set` (that is, the type of `Set` is `Set` itself) and reconstruct [Russell's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox):

```
{-# OPTIONS --type-in-type #-}
module Boom where

open import Data.Empty
open import Data.Product
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality

data M : Set where
  m : (I : Set) → (I → M) → M

_∈_ : M → M → Set
a ∈ m I f = Σ I λ i → a ≡ f i

_∉_ : M → M → Set
a ∉ b = (a ∈ b) → ⊥

-- Set of all sets that are not members of themselves.
R : M
R = m (Σ M λ a → a ∉ a) proj₁

-- If a set belongs to R, it does not contain itself.
lem₁ : ∀ {X} → X ∈ R → X ∉ X
lem₁ ((Y , Y∉Y) , refl) = Y∉Y

-- If a set does not contain itself, then it is in R.
lem₂ : ∀ {X} → X ∉ X → X ∈ R
lem₂ X∉X = (_ , X∉X) , refl

-- R does not contain itself.
lem₃ : R ∉ R
lem₃ R∈R = lem₁ R∈R R∈R

-- But R also contains itself - a paradox.
lem₄ : R ∈ R
lem₄ = lem₂ lem₃

loop : {A : Set} → A
loop = ⊥-elim (lem₃ lem₄)
```

([source](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~txa/g53cfr/l20.html/l20.html)). We could also write a variant of Girard's paradox, [simplified by A.J.C. Hurkens](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kw/scans/hurkens95tlca.pdf):

```
{-# OPTIONS --type-in-type #-}
module Boom where

⊥   = ∀ p → p
¬_  = λ A → A → ⊥
℘_  = λ A → A → Set
℘℘_ = λ A → ℘ ℘ A

U = (X : Set) → (℘℘ X → X) → ℘℘ X

τ : ℘℘ U → U
τ t = λ (X : Set) (f : ℘℘ X → X) (p : ℘ X) → t λ (x : U) → p (f (x X f))

σ : U → ℘℘ U
σ s = s U λ (t : ℘℘ U) → τ t

τσ : U → U
τσ x = τ (σ x)

Δ = λ (y : U) → ¬ (∀ (p : ℘ U) → σ y p → p (τσ y))
Ω = τ λ (p : ℘ U) → ∀ (x : U) → σ x p → p x

loop : (A : Set) → A
loop = (λ (₀ : ∀ (p : ℘ U) → (∀ (x : U) → σ x p → p x) → p Ω) →
  (₀ Δ λ (x : U) (₂ : σ x Δ) (₃ : ∀ (p : ℘ U) → σ x p → p (τσ x)) →
  (₃ Δ ₂ λ (p : ℘ U) → (₃ λ (y : U) → p (τσ y)))) λ (p : ℘ U) →
  ₀ λ (y : U) → p (τσ y)) λ (p : ℘ U) (₁ : ∀ (x : U) → σ x p → p x) →
  ₁ Ω λ (x : U) → ₁ (τσ x)
```

This one is a real mess, though. But it has a nice property that it uses only dependent functions. Strangely, it doesn't even get past type checking and causes `agda` to loop. Splitting the whole `loop` term into two helps.

Answer (score 6):

The syntax highlighting you are seeing is a compile error.  The termination checker's effect is to highlight non-terminating functions in a kind of pink-orange color ("salmon"). You may notice that a module containing such an error cannot be imported from other modules.  It can also not be compiled down to Haskell.

So yes, Agda programs always terminate and this is not a bug.